# How to extract value of a column based on multiple other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
>head(df)

chrom   pos strand  ref alt A_pos   A_neg   C_pos   C_neg   G_pos   G_neg   T_pos   T_neg
chr1    2283161 -   G   A   3       1       2       0       0       0        0      0
chr1    2283161 -   G   A   3       1       2       0       0       0        0      0
chr1    2283313 -   G   C   0       0       0       0       0       0        0      0
chr1    2283313 -   G   C   0       0       0       0       0       0        0      0
chr1    2283896 -   G   A   0       0       0       0       0       0        0      0
chr1    2283896 +   G   A   0       0       0       0       0       0        0      0
```

I want to extract the value from columns 6:13 (A_pos...T_neg) based on the value of the columns 'strand', 'ref' and 'alt'. For instance, in row1: strand = '-', ref = 'G' and alt = 'A', so I should extract the values from G_neg and A_neg. Again, in row6: stand = '+', ref = 'G' and alt = 'A', so I should get the values from G_pos and A_pos. I basically intend to do a chi-square test after extracting these values (These are my observed values, I have another set of expected values) but that is another story.

So the logic is somewhat like:

```
if(df$strand=="+")
do
  print:paste(df$ref,"pos",sep="_") #extract value in column df$ref_pos
  print:paste(df$alt,"pos",sep="_") #extract value in column df$alt_pos

else if(gt.merge$gene_strand=="-")
do
  print:paste(df$ref,"neg",sep="_") #extract value in column df$ref_neg
  print:paste(df$alt,"neg",sep="_") #extract value in column df$alt_neg
```

Here, I am trying to use paste on the values in 'ref' and 'alt' to get the desired column names. For instance, if strand ='+' and ref = 'G', it will fetch value from column G_pos.

The data frame is actually large and so I ruled out using for-loops. I am not sure how else can I do this to make the code as efficient as possible. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative that looks valid, at least with the sample data:

```
tmp = ifelse(as.character(DF$strand) == "-", "neg", "pos")
sapply(DF[c("ref", "alt")], 
       function(x) as.integer(DF[cbind(seq_len(nrow(DF)), 
                                       match(paste(x, tmp, sep = "_"), names(DF)))]))
#     ref alt
#[1,]   0   1
#[2,]   0   1
#[3,]   0   0
#[4,]   0   0
#[5,]   0   0
#[6,]   0   0
```

Where `DF`:

```
DF = structure(list(chrom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr1", class = "factor"), 
    pos = c(2283161L, 2283161L, 2283313L, 2283313L, 2283896L, 
    2283896L), strand = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("-", 
    "+"), class = "factor"), ref = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "G", class = "factor"), alt = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    A_pos = c(3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A_neg = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), C_pos = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C_neg = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G_pos = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G_neg = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T_pos = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), T_neg = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("chrom", "pos", "strand", 
"ref", "alt", "A_pos", "A_neg", "C_pos", "C_neg", "G_pos", "G_neg", 
"T_pos", "T_neg"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but does the job:

```
strand.map <- c("-"="_neg", "+"="_pos")
cbind(
  df[1:5],
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(
      split(df[-(1:2)], 1:nrow(df)), 
      function(x) 
        c(
          ref=x[-(1:2)][, paste0(x[[2]], strand.map[x[[1]]])], 
          alt=x[-(1:2)][, paste0(x[[3]], strand.map[x[[1]]])]
) ) ) )
```

We cycle through each row in your data frame and apply a function that pulls the value based on `strand`, `ref`, and `alt`.  This produces:

```
  chrom     pos strand ref alt ref alt
1  chr1 2283161      -   G   A   0   1
2  chr1 2283161      -   G   A   0   1
3  chr1 2283313      -   G   C   0   0
4  chr1 2283313      -   G   C   0   0
5  chr1 2283896      -   G   A   0   0
6  chr1 2283896      +   G   A   0   0
```

An alternate approach is to use `melt`, but the format of your data makes it rather annoying because we need two melts in a row, and we need to create a unique id column so we can reconstitute the data frame once we're done computing.

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
df.mlt <- 
  melt(
    melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "chrom", "pos", "strand", "ref", "alt")),
    measure.vars=c("ref", "alt"), value.name="base",
    variable.name="alt_or_ref"
  )
dcast(
  subset(df.mlt, paste0(base, strand.map[strand]) == variable),
  id + chrom + pos + strand ~ alt_or_ref,
  value.var="value"
)
```

Which produces:

```
  id chrom     pos strand ref alt
1  1  chr1 2283161      -   0   1
2  2  chr1 2283161      -   0   1
3  3  chr1 2283313      -   0   0
4  4  chr1 2283313      -   0   0
5  5  chr1 2283896      -   0   0
6  6  chr1 2283896      +   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
testFunc <- function(x){
  posneg <- if(x["strand"] == "-") {"neg"} else {"pos"}
  cbind(as.numeric(x[paste0(x["ref"],"_",posneg)]), as.numeric(x[paste0(x["alt"],"_",posneg)]))
  }
temp <- t(apply(df, 1, testFunc))
colnames(temp) <- c("ref", "alt")
```

Answer (score 0):

using the [very] fast data.table library:

```
library(data.table)    

df = fread('df.txt') # fastread

df[,ref := ifelse(strand == "-",
                   paste(ref,"neg",sep = "_"),
                   paste(ref,"pos",sep = "_"))]
df[,alt := ifelse(strand == "-",
                   paste(alt,"neg",sep = "_"),
                   paste(alt,"pos",sep = "_"))]
df[,strand := NULL] # not required anymore

dfm = melt(df, 
       id.vars = c("chrom","pos","ref","alt"), 
       variable.name = "mycol", value.name = "value")

dfm[mycol == ref | mycol == alt,] # matching
```

Comment: I tried using this and when I apply the melt function it shows me this error:                                                    Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. How does your data.table look like? For fread(df.txt) you have to place the path and the name of your raw data file, e.g. fread("/downloads/stackoverflow.txt").